# com.dhtmlx.connector.JSONOptionsConnector cannot be cast to com.dhtmlx.connector.OptionsConnector

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, dhtmlx

I have these two tables:gantt_tasks and gantt_links, I succeed to add tasks to the first table but I had this error if I try to add a link.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dhtmlx.connector.JSONOptionsConnector cannot be cast to com.dhtmlx.connector.OptionsConnector
```

Here my page html and my servlet Conector :

index.html

```
<body>
  <div id="idGantt" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
            gantt.config.scale_unit = "day";
            gantt.config.duration_unit = "day";
            gantt.config.date_scale = "%d";
            gantt.init("idGantt");
            gantt.load("Conector");
            var dp = new  dataProcessor("Conector");
            dp.init(gantt);
    </script>
</body>
```

Conector.java

```
public class Conector extends ThreadSafeConnectorServlet  {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
   Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONGanttConnector gantt = new JSONGanttConnector(conn, DBType.MySQL);
    gantt.servlet(req, res);

    gantt.mix("open", "1");

 gantt.enable_order("sortorder");
 gantt.render_links("gantt_links", "id", "source,target,type");

 gantt.render_table("gantt_tasks", "id", "start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent");

}
}
```

Help please, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I dowloaded the updated connector.jar from here [conector.jar](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=40534&p=125083#p125083) and it work's very well.